# What is the word *then* doing in "The constant synthesis, **then**, of specific material from simple....",?

Tags: sentence-construction, commas, syntax, academic-writing

It was usually considered that the most characteristic feature of life is its
metabolism.

> " The constant synthesis, **then**, of specific  material from simple
> compounds of a non-specific character is the chief feature by which
> living matter differs from non-living matter"

,was the way it was expressed by Jacques Loeb in 1916

What is the word **then** between commas doing?, is it describing time or anything else?

My rephrasing of quoted text is that ***synthesis of specific material from compounds that are non specific nature is the difference between organic and inorganic***
If my above rephrase is wrong, I would really appreciate if anyone can rephrase the quoted text in simpler form

Comment: then refers to something in a previous explanation or sentence.

Comment: Your rephrasing is not quite accurate. The synthesis is a feature that makes a difference, not "the difference" itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is expressing that what he is saying in that sentence is the consequence of something he said previously. He could have started the sentence with *then*, or he could have used *so*:

> So, the constant synthesis... is the chief feature...

[Merriam-Webster *then*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/then)

> adverb : as it appears : by way of summing up
> *the cause of the accident, then, is established*

The  M-W example could also be rephrased

> So, the cause of the accident is established.